# Default SynchronizationContext vs Default TaskScheduler

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task-parallel-library, async-await

This is going to be a bit long, so please bear with me.

I was thinking that the behavior of the default task scheduler (`ThreadPoolTaskScheduler`) is very similar to that of the default "`ThreadPool`" [`SynchronizationContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (the latter can be referenced implicitly via `await` or explicitly via `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()`). They both schedule tasks to be executed on a random `ThreadPool` thread. In fact, `SynchronizationContext.Post` merely calls `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem`.

However, there is a subtle but important difference in how `TaskCompletionSource.SetResult` works, when used from a task queued on the default `SynchronizationContext`. Here's a simple console app illustrating it:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleTcs
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task TcsTest(TaskScheduler taskScheduler)
        {
            var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();

            var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    Console.WriteLine("before tcs.SetResult, thread: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
                    tcs.SetResult(true);
                    Console.WriteLine("after tcs.SetResult, thread: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
                    Thread.Sleep(2000);
                },
                CancellationToken.None,
                TaskCreationOptions.None,
                taskScheduler);

            Console.WriteLine("before await tcs.Task, thread: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
            await tcs.Task.ConfigureAwait(true);
            Console.WriteLine("after await tcs.Task, thread: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

            await task.ConfigureAwait(true);
            Console.WriteLine("after await task, thread: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        }

        // Main
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // SynchronizationContext.Current is null
            // install default SynchronizationContext on the thread
            SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(new SynchronizationContext());

            // use TaskScheduler.Default for Task.Factory.StartNew
            Console.WriteLine("Test #1, thread: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
            TcsTest(TaskScheduler.Default).Wait();

            // use TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext() for Task.Factory.StartNew
            Console.WriteLine("\nTest #2, thread: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
            TcsTest(TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()).Wait();

            Console.WriteLine("\nPress enter to exit, thread: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

The output:

```
Test #1, thread: 9
before await tcs.Task, thread: 9
before tcs.SetResult, thread: 10
after await tcs.Task, thread: 10
after tcs.SetResult, thread: 10
after await task, thread: 10

Test #2, thread: 9
before await tcs.Task, thread: 9
before tcs.SetResult, thread: 10
after tcs.SetResult, thread: 10
after await tcs.Task, thread: 11
after await task, thread: 11

Press enter to exit, thread: 9
```

This is a console app, its `Main` thread doesn't have any synchronization context by default, so I explicitly install the default one at the beginning, before running tests: `SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(new SynchronizationContext())`.

Initially, I thought I fully comprehended the execution workflow during the test #1 (where the task is scheduled with `TaskScheduler.Default`). There `tcs.SetResult` synchronously invokes the first continuation part (`await tcs.Task`), then the execution point returns to `tcs.SetResult` and continues synchronously ever after, including the second `await task`. That did make sense to me, **until I realized the following**. As we now have the default synchronization context installed on the thread that does `await tcs.Task`, it should be captured and the continuation should occur *asynchronously* (i.e., on a different pool thread as queued by `SynchronizationContext.Post`). By analogy, if I ran the test #1 from within a WinForms app, it would have been continued asynchronously after `await tcs.Task`, on `WinFormsSynchronizationContext` upon a future iteration of the message loop.

But that's not what happens inside the test #1. Out of curiosity, I changed `ConfigureAwait(true)` **to `ConfigureAwait(false)`** and that did **not** have any effect on the output. I'm looking for an explanation of this.

Now, during the test #2 (the task is scheduled with `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()`) there's indeed one more thread switch, as compared to #1. As can been seen from the output, the `await tcs.Task` continuation triggered by `tcs.SetResult` does happen asynchronously, on another pool thread. I tried `ConfigureAwait(false)` too, that didn't change anything either. I also **tried installing `SynchronizationContext` immediately before starting the test #2**, rather than at the beginning. That resulted in exactly the same output, either.

I actually like the behavior of the test #2 more, because it leaves less gap for side effects (and, potentially, deadlocks) which may be caused by the synchronous continuation triggered by `tcs.SetResult`, even though it comes at a price of an extra thread switch. However, I don't fully understand **why** such thread switch takes place regardless of `ConfigureAwait(false)`.

I'm familiar with the following excellent resources on the subject, but I'm still looking for a good explanation of the behaviors seen in test #1 and #2. **Can someone please elaborate on this?**

[The Nature of TaskCompletionSource](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2009/06/02/9685804.aspx)
[Parallel Programming: Task Schedulers and Synchronization Context](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/06/18/parallel-programming-task-schedulers-and-synchronization-context.aspx)
[Parallel Programming: TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2009/09/22/9898090.aspx)
[It's All About the SynchronizationContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg598924.aspx)

---

**[UPDATE]** My point is, the default synchronization context object has been explicitly installed on the main thread, before the thread hits the first `await tcs.Task` in test #1. IMO, the fact that it is not a GUI synchronization context doesn't mean it should not be captured for continuation after `await`. That's why I expect the continuation after `tcs.SetResult` to take place on a different thread from the `ThreadPool` (queued there by `SynchronizationContext.Post`), while the main thread may still be blocked by `TcsTest(...).Wait()`. This is a very similar scenario to the [one described here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/01/20/10259049.aspx).

So I went ahead and **implemented a dumb synchronization context class** `TestSyncContext`, which is *just a wrapper* around `SynchronizationContext`. It's now installed instead of the `SynchronizationContext` itself:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleTcs
{
    public class TestSyncContext : SynchronizationContext
    {
        public override void Post(SendOrPostCallback d, object state)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("TestSyncContext.Post, thread: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
            base.Post(d, state);
        }

        public override void Send(SendOrPostCallback d, object state)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("TestSyncContext.Send, thread: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
            base.Send(d, state);
        }
    };

    class Program
    {
        static async Task TcsTest(TaskScheduler taskScheduler)
        {
            var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();

            var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    Console.WriteLine("before tcs.SetResult, thread: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
                    tcs.SetResult(true);
                    Console.WriteLine("after tcs.SetResult, thread: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
                    Thread.Sleep(2000);
                },
                CancellationToken.None,
                TaskCreationOptions.None,
                taskScheduler);

            Console.WriteLine("before await tcs.Task, thread: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
            await tcs.Task.ConfigureAwait(true);
            Console.WriteLine("after await tcs.Task, thread: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
            await task.ConfigureAwait(true);
            Console.WriteLine("after await task, thread: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        }

        // Main
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // SynchronizationContext.Current is null
            // install default SynchronizationContext on the thread
            SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(new TestSyncContext());

            // use TaskScheduler.Default for Task.Factory.StartNew
            Console.WriteLine("Test #1, thread: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
            TcsTest(TaskScheduler.Default).Wait();

            // use TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext() for Task.Factory.StartNew
            Console.WriteLine("\nTest #2, thread: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
            TcsTest(TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()).Wait();

            Console.WriteLine("\nPress enter to exit, thread: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

**Magically, things have changed in a better way!** Here's the new output:

```
Test #1, thread: 10
before await tcs.Task, thread: 10
before tcs.SetResult, thread: 6
TestSyncContext.Post, thread: 6
after tcs.SetResult, thread: 6
after await tcs.Task, thread: 11
after await task, thread: 6

Test #2, thread: 10
TestSyncContext.Post, thread: 10
before await tcs.Task, thread: 10
before tcs.SetResult, thread: 11
TestSyncContext.Post, thread: 11
after tcs.SetResult, thread: 11
after await tcs.Task, thread: 12
after await task, thread: 12

Press enter to exit, thread: 10
```

Now test #1 now behaves as expected (`await tcs.Task` is asynchronously queued to a pool thread). #2 appears to be OK, too. Let's change `ConfigureAwait(true)` to `ConfigureAwait(false)`:

```
Test #1, thread: 9
before await tcs.Task, thread: 9
before tcs.SetResult, thread: 10
after await tcs.Task, thread: 10
after tcs.SetResult, thread: 10
after await task, thread: 10

Test #2, thread: 9
TestSyncContext.Post, thread: 9
before await tcs.Task, thread: 9
before tcs.SetResult, thread: 11
after tcs.SetResult, thread: 11
after await tcs.Task, thread: 10
after await task, thread: 10

Press enter to exit, thread: 9
```

Test #1 still behaves correctly as expected: `ConfigureAwait(false)` makes the `await tcs.Task` ignore the synchronization context (the `TestSyncContext.Post` call is gone), so now it continues synchronously after `tcs.SetResult`.

**Why is this different from the case when the default `SynchronizationContext` is used?** I'm still curious to know. Perhaps, the default task scheduler (which is responsible for `await` continuations) checks the runtime type information of the thread's synchronization context, and give some special treatment to `SynchronizationContext`?

Now, I still can't explain the behavior of test #2 for when `ConfigureAwait(false)`. It's one less `TestSyncContext.Post` call, that's understood. However, `await tcs.Task` still gets continued on a different thread from `tcs.SetResult` (unlike in #1), that's not what I'd expect. I'm still seeking for a reason for this.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

When you start diving this deep into the implementation details, it's important to differentiate between documented/reliable behavior and undocumented behavior. Also, it's not really considered proper to have `SynchronizationContext.Current` set to `new SynchronizationContext()`; some types in .NET treat `null` as the default scheduler, and other types treat `null` *or* `new SynchronizationContext()` as the default scheduler.

When you `await` an incomplete `Task`, the `TaskAwaiter` by default captures the current `SynchronizationContext` - unless it is `null` (or its `GetType` returns `typeof(SynchronizationContext)`), in which case the `TaskAwaiter` captures the current `TaskScheduler`. This behavior is mostly documented (the `GetType` clause is not AFAIK). However, please note that this describes the behavior of `TaskAwaiter`, not `TaskScheduler.Default` or `TaskFactory.StartNew`.

After the context (if any) is captured, then `await` schedules a continuation. This continuation is scheduled [using `ExecuteSynchronously`](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/12/dont-block-in-asynchronous-code.html), as described on my blog (this behavior is undocumented). However, do note that [`ExecuteSynchronously` does not always execute synchronously](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/02/07/10265067.aspx); in particular, if a continuation has a task scheduler, it will only *request* to execute synchronously on the current thread, and the task scheduler has the option to refuse to execute it synchronously (also undocumented).

Finally, note that a `TaskScheduler` can be requested to execute a task synchronously, but a `SynchronizationContext` cannot. So, if the `await` captures a custom `SynchronizationContext`, then it must *always* execute the continuation asynchronously.

So, in your original Test #1:

- `StartNew` starts a new task with the default task scheduler (on thread 10).
- `SetResult` synchronously executes the continuation set by `await tcs.Task`.
- At the end of the `StartNew` task, it synchronously executes the continuation set by `await task`.

In your original Test #2:

- `StartNew` starts a new task with a task scheduler wrapper for a default-constructed synchronization context (on thread 10). Note that the task on thread 10 has `TaskScheduler.Current` set to a `SynchronizationContextTaskScheduler` whose `m_synchronizationContext` is the instance created by `new SynchronizationContext()`; however, that thread's `SynchronizationContext.Current` is `null`.
- `SetResult` attempts to execute the `await tcs.Task` continuation synchronously on the current task scheduler; however, it cannot because `SynchronizationContextTaskScheduler` sees that thread 10 has a `SynchronizationContext.Current` of `null` while it is requiring a `new SynchronizationContext()`. Thus, it schedules the continuation asynchronously (on thread 11).
- A similar situation happens at the end of the `StartNew` task; in this case, I believe it's coincidental that the `await task` continues on the same thread.

In conclusion, I must emphasize that depending on undocumented implementation details is not wise. If you want to have your `async` method continue on a thread pool thread, then wrap it in a `Task.Run`. That will make the intent of your code much clearer, and also make your code more resilient to future framework updates. Also, don't set `SynchronizationContext.Current` to `new SynchronizationContext()`, since the handling of that scenario is inconsistent.

Comment: Does the default `SynchronizationContext` ever get used directly anywhere in the Framework (besides for deriving from it)? I wonder why they did not make it `abstract`.

Comment: I agree it's not the best design. There are a number of local uses like `localContext = SynchronizationContext.Current ?? new SynchronizationContext()`. But I haven't gone through the whole framework. :)

Answer (score 4):

`SynchronizationContext` always simply calls `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` on the post--which explains why you always see a different thread in test #2.

In test #1 you're using a smarter `TaskScheduler`.  `await` is supposed to continue on the same thread (or ["stay on the current thread"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/10/29/asynchronous-programming-in-c-5-0-part-two-whence-await.aspx) ).  In a Console app there's no way to "schedule" return to the main thread like there is in message-queue-based UI frameworks. An `await` in a console application would have to block the main thread until the work is done (leaving the main thread with nothing to do) in order to continue on that same thread.  If the scheduler *knows* this, then it might as well run the code synchronously on the same thread as it would have the same result without having to create another thread and risk a context switch.

More information can be found here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/01/20/10259049.aspx

**Update**:
In terms of the `ConfigureAwait`.  Console applications have no way to "marshal" back to the main thread so, presumably, `ConfigureAwait(false)` means nothing in a console app.

See also: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx

Comment: Hmm, in fact I'm not expecting the `await tcs.Task` to continue on the same thread in test #1. **I would, if I did not install the sync. context.** But once it's there when I do the `await`, I expect it to be captured (as it's `ConfigureAwait(true)`) and used for continuation, so it would be posted to another pool thread. Why doesn't this happen?

Comment: That's what `await` does--as a means of more easily writing asynchronous code in a GUI-based applications.  This is because operations on GUI controls need to happen on the one and only GUI thread--thus everything *after* `await` defaults to continuing on the same thread.  In a console app, the main thread cannot be asynchronous (if it were, it could exit before async operations complete) and has no way for `await` to marshal back to it in the continuation.

Comment: I use `TcsTest(...).Wait()` to avoid premature exit in the main thread of my console app, so this is not an issue: the main thread is blocked while waiting. At the same time, I can put `await Task.Delay(1000)` or simply `await Task.Yield()` at the beginning of `TcsTest`, and execution will continue every time on a new thread after such `await`, while the main thread is still waiting, verified.

Comment: [This experiment](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20944879/1768303) shows that `ConfigureAwait` works in a console app, at least for a custom synchronization context. Perhaps, it is *not* for the standard `SynchronizationContext`?

Comment: How does that experiment show that ConfigureAwait "works"?  You don't compare it to using the `false` parameter.

Comment: I do compare, actually: for `ConfigureAwait(false)` the context is not captured in the updated #1, the fact that `TestSyncContext.Post` is no longer called shows that, as opposed to the `ConfigureAwait(true)` case.