# C# Reusing thread that runs the Main method in a console application

Tags: c#, multithreading, task, threadpool

I have the following code:

```cs
static async Task Main()
{
    // Save the id of the thread that runs Main
    var n = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;

    // We will be working in a different thread 
    var _ = Task.Run(() =>
    {
        // We will periodically do this:
        while (true)
        {
            // Get some input

            // Process it in a different thread
            Task.Run(() =>
            {
                // Assume I do some heavy calculations here...

                // Does every happen that the thread which runs Main is here?
                if (Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId == n)
                    Console.WriteLine("It happens");

                // It turns out it does not :/
            });
        }
    });

    // Keep the application alive
    await Task.Delay(-1);
}
```

When I run this, I will never see `It happens` printed. I would like that to happen because now it seems to me like the thread that runs the Main method is doing nothing and I think it is a good idea to reuse it for the heavy computation. Can I change `await Task.Delay(-1)` to achieve so?

Comment: Why not simply `await Task.Run()`?

Comment: It's not so simple. [Does this answer your question?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/await-synchronizationcontext-and-console-apps/)

Comment: Short version: `Task.Run()` by default will _never_ execute the task on the original thread, even when a synchronization context exists, and in a console program it doesn't. If a synchronization context exists, the continuation of an `async` method (i.e. after `await` completes) is run in that context if a) the `await` itself was executed in the context, and b) the behavior wasn't modified by calling `ConfigureAwait(false)`. See marked duplicate for more explanation. The `Task.Run()` task is run in a thread determined by the scheduler, which by default uses the thread pool only.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20300164/run-code-in-main-thread, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20942253/default-synchronizationcontext-vs-default-taskscheduler, and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52686862/why-the-default-synchronizationcontext-is-not-captured-in-a-console-app